# Transform TranslateZ is not working on Mac safari 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, css-transforms

I am implementing pure CSS parallax. Its working on Chrome but not working on 
Firefox and Mac Safari-11. Please find example as below.

I am trying this one ( https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw ). Most part of this example is working in safari. But when i am trying to implement the parallax effect of two small images that are using rotate property, its working perfectly in chrome but on mac safari 11 parallax effects not working.

I have tried to use webkit for safari:-

```
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
```

And also tried:-

```
backface-visibility: visible;
```

```
<div id="slide2" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/"> 
</div>

<div id="slide3" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Nunito;
}
h1 {
   font-size: 250%
}
p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
img:last-of-type {
  transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
}
.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}
#title {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/");
  z-index:2;
}

#title h1 {
 transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75);
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;

}
#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
#slide2 {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/3/");
  z-index:2;
}
#slide3:before {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/5/");

}
</style>
```

Anyone please help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what do you mean by "stopped working"? If you could be a little more specific, the community might be able to help you faster.